# How do I get the latest record?

Tags: hive, distinct, records

This is my table:

```
create table test (
id string,
name string,
age string,
modified string)
```

and this is my data:

```
id    name   age  modifed
1     a      10   2011-11-11 11:11:11
1     a      11   2012-11-11 12:00:00
2     b      20   2012-12-10 10:11:12
2     b      20   2012-12-10 10:11:12
2     b      20   2012-12-12 10:11:12
2     b      20   2012-12-15 10:11:12
```

I want to get the latest record (include every columns id,name,age,modified) group by id,as the data above,the correct result is:

```
1     a      11   2012-11-11 12:00:00
2     b      20   2012-12-15 10:11:12
```

I am using below query in hive, it is working fine in sql http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bfbd5/42 but it is not working fine in hive

```
select * from test where (id, modified) in(select id, max(modified) from test group by id)
```

I am using 0.13 version of hive.

Answer (score 0):

Hive only allows one column in an IN subquery.  Try a left semijoin:

```
SELECT *
FROM test a 
LEFT SEMI JOIN 
(select id, max(modified) as modified from test) b 
ON (a.modified = b.modified and a.id=b.id);
```

It sure seems like you could easily get he right answer using a straight forward query though.  Select the max of the two columns and be sure to group by the columns that don't have aggregate functions.

```
select id
, name
, max(age) as age
, max(modified) as modified
from test
group by id, name;
```